# Freewall problems in mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, grid

Hello stackoverflow I need help, I've got 300px width blocks like in this link: http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/demo-filter.html and try to resize window until mobile, blocks vanish... How can we solve this problem? I was surfing all over the Internet and I can't find problem here is what values I used:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".free-wall").each(function() {
        var wall = new freewall(this);;
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.size320',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 200,
            cellH: 'auto',
            onResize: function() {
                wall.fitWidth();
            }
        });
        wall.fitWidth();
    });
});
```